# Problem while upgrading to JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to upgrade my application from JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.0. I just replaced the latest JSR files and got the following exception. May be some problem in the configuration.

> SEVERE: Exception sending context
>   initialized event to listener instance
>   of class
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
>   java.util.MissingResourceException:
>   Can't find bundle for base name label,
>   locale en_US

Post your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is basically telling that you have a `<resource-bundle>` with the `<base-name>` `label` definied in your old `faces-config.xml`, but yet the concrete files like `label.properties`, `label_en.properties`, etc are missing in the root of the classpath.

I'm not sure how this is related to upgrade from JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.0. Maybe you removed too much or the `faces-config` is still declared as JSF 1.1 (for which the behaviour of JSF 2.0 is unspecified and for which I also can't tell from own experience *what* would then happen, I've only played around JSF 1.2 --> JSF 2.0). A proper JSF 2.0 `faces-config.xml` declaration starts as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- Config here -->

</faces-config>
```

Comment: I am not sure why it is giving error. I think some issues in the configuration. When I put the JSF 2.0 jars, its giving the problem

Comment: Probably you have some old JSF 1.1 specific entries in `web.xml` or `faces-config.xml`. First would be to look for any JSF 1.1 specific `<context-param>` and `<listener>` entries in `web.xml` and then remove/replace them. Update your question to include them if you're unsure. I would however recommend to let your IDE create a brand new JSF 2.0 project first and then play around it. By coincidence, I have yesterday posted a new JSF 2.0 tutorial for Eclipse 3.6 and Glassfish 3: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html. You may find it useful.